# TaskFactory.Startnew, UI hangs when Long running Task is processing

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, task

I'm trying to run an asynchronous task using TaskFactory (Framework 4)  with LongRunning parameter,
I show a loading panel but the ui hangs and the dynamic gif is not rendering properly.

I supposed that firing this task after showing the panel would be done in a separate thread
so the UI would be free to display my loading image but it gets stuck.

There is not more code after the task launch. Everything else is controlled in the callback funciton.

How can I do this loading image to display without hangs?

```
'HERE I MAKE VISIBLE MY LOADING PANEL
panelCargando.Visible = True

'I START A LONG RUNNING TASK with callback
Dim context As TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext

        Task(Of ContratoType). _
            Factory.StartNew(Function()

                                 Dim contrato As ResultadoTarificacionType = Me.Tarificador.TarificarContrato(datosContrato, Nothing, 25000)

                                 Dim estadoContacto As EstadoProductoContratoType() = Tarificador.ObtenerEstadosTarificacion(contrato.IdContrato)

                                 'Dim estadoProductoTarif As EstadoProductoContratoType() = Tarificador.ObtenerEstadosTarificacionProductos(contrato.IdContrato )
                                 Return Tarificador.ObtenerContrato(contrato.IdContrato)

                             End Function, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, context) _
        .ContinueWith(Sub(r)
                          TaskCallBack(r)
                      End Sub, context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're explicitly using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`. That means your long-running task will be running on the UI thread - you told it to!

What I suspect your really want is to use the default task scheduler for the long-running task, but pass `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` into your `ContinueWith` call, so that just the callback is executed on the UI thread.

Comment: That Is what I was suspecting. I'm gonna try it. Thanks @Jon Skeet